# remove specific string in python2.7

Tags: python

I have a list as follows:

```
>>> header
['Id', ["['GSM1172844_184A1.txt', 'GSM1384316_MDAMB453.txt']"]]
>>> type(header)
list
```

And, how can I change it to a string as follows;

```
['Id','GSM1172844_184A1.txt', 'GSM1384316_MDAMB453.txt']
```

I'm try used `re.split('\[|\]|\"',str(header))` . But the resulted is not I want to get.

```
['',
 "'Id', ",
 '',
 '',
 "'GSM1172844_184A1.txt', 'GSM1384316_MDAMB453.txt'",
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '']
```

So, any suggestion is hope.

Comment: Where did the data come from? Why can't you fix the issue there?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying.

Comment: Please show where `header` is assigned by editing your question with a [mcve] of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
>>> header = ['Id', ["['GSM1172844_184A1.txt', 'GSM1384316_MDAMB453.txt']"]]
>>> str(header).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('"','').replace("'",'').split(', ')
['Id', 'GSM1172844_184A1.txt', 'GSM1384316_MDAMB453.txt']
```

Comment: And want to trim the strings

Comment: Indeed. It's fixed.

Comment: Yes,  why have  "\" appear when I directed `str(header)`  `'[\'Id\', ["[\'GSM1172844_184A1.txt\', \'GSM1384316_MDAMB453.txt\']"]]'`

Comment: Because in type conversion, special characters like `'` have to be escaped.

Comment: As your code (`replace("\'",'')`), this backslash that appears when type conversion can operation just as the normal string.

Answer (score 0):

```
parsed = header[:1] + eval(header[1][0])
```

This will work if you always have the exact format you have in the example and the second string has a proper Python syntax.

Comment: Thanks, Let me learning a new Built-in Functions [eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval).

Comment: Why not use `ast` module to evaluate that list?

Comment: @cricket_007 'ast.literal_eval ' raises an exception if the input isn't a valid Python datatype, so the code won't be executed if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

How about using regular expressions?

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: re.findall("[A-Za-z0-9_\.]+", str(header))
Out[2]: ['Id', 'GSM1172844_184A1.txt', 'GSM1384316_MDAMB453.txt']
```